# How to put a list of dfs side by side based on a single column values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of df that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':["A"],'Level': [1],'Part':["Upper"]})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':["A","A"],'Level': [1,2],'Part':["Upper 2 System","Upper 2 stock"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':["ABC","ABC"],'Level': [1,3],'Part':["Upper System","Middle"]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':["AAB","AAB","AAB"],'Level': [1,4,2],'Part':["Limits System","Deck","Ceiling"]})

    Name    Level   Part
0   A          1    Upper

    Name    Level   Part
0   A          1    Upper 2 System
1   A          2    Upper 2 stock

    Name    Level   Part
0   ABC        1    Upper System
1   ABC        3    Middle

    Name    Level   Part
0   AAB        1    Limits System
1   AAB        4    Deck
2   AAB        2    Ceiling
```

I need it to look like this. They need to be seperated by the Name column and be side by side. The column titles can be removed if needed, but the dfs still have to be separated. Also, the order does not matter. Nothing I've tried has worked and if it is not possible just let me know.

```
    Name    Level   Part                 Name    Level   Part             Name    Level   Part
0   A          1    Upper            0   ABC        1    Upper System   0 AAB        1    Limits System
                                     1   ABC        3    Middle         1 AAB        4    Deck
    Name    Level   Part                                                2 AAB        2    Ceiling
0   A          1    Upper 2 System
1   A          2    Upper 2 stock
```

Comment: ```pd.concat([df, df1, df2, df3], axis=1)```?

Comment: added a solution. does it work?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It's close but I need all the dfs with the same name in the same column. so the two df["Name"] == 'A' should be under each other. The name ABC and ABB also have more dfs that need to go under their columns.

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to do it

use pd.concat and drop the index when resetting index for each of the individual df

```
pd.concat([df.reset_index(drop=True), 
           df1.reset_index(drop=True),
           df2.reset_index(drop=True),
           df3.reset_index(drop=True)
          ], axis=1 ).fillna('')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It's close but I need all the dfs with the same name in the same column. so the two df["Name"] == 'A' should be under each other. The name ABC and ABB also have more dfs that need to go under their columns.